# How do array_udiff(), array_uintersect() etc. work?

Tags: php, arrays, anonymous-function

There are a couple of similar questions here on SO, but I still haven't found an answer.

PHP manual states that

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

The thing is that I don't understand why is it so important to have three optional outcomes, like `-1`, `0` and `1`? Why wouldn't it work out if I used `0` for cases when two values being compared are equal and 1 otherwise?

---

A more practical question: I have a task where I should find elements of the first array that exist in the second one. The structures of the arrays are the same and look like the following:

```
 Array
  (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [productId] => 5479046275
              [options] => Array
                  (
                      [1] => All
                      [2] => Green
                  )
          )
  )
```

So I consider elements of such arrays equal when `productId` values match, and when there's no difference between options respecting their keys. Comparing options should be performed with the fact that 'All' options match every other's value. So I have a code like this:

```
    $cartItems = <MyArray>;
    $triggers = <MyAnotherArray>;
    /**
     * Options equal each other when they are exactly the same or
     * when bundle offer's product has 'All' selected as option. 
     */
    $compareOptions = function ($a, $b) {
        if ('All' == $b) {
            return 0;
        } 

        return strcmp($a, $b);
    };

    /**
     * Compare product id to make sure these variants are of the same product
     * Then check the options. If there's no difference, then variants 
     * are equal
     */
    $compareVariants = function ($a, $b) use ($compareOptions) {
        if ($a['productId'] != $b['productId']) {
            return ($a['productId'] > $b['productId']) ? 1 : -1;
        }
        $optionsDiff = array_udiff_assoc($a['options'], $b['options'], $compareOptions);
        if (0 === count($optionsDiff)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return (count($optionsDiff) > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    };

    return array_uintersect($cartItems, $triggers, $compareVariants);
```

Then I xDebugged it. For some reason, when $optionsDiff is empty and script returns 0, it doesn't not step out of $compareVariants function, but goes to $compareOptions comparing arrays which produces a error.

Why does it work like that?

Thanks.

Comment: To answer your first question ~ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison

Answer (score 0):

array_udiff_assoc() will compare the keys using built-in function and values will be compared using user-defined function.

```
array_udiff_assoc($array1,$array2,"userDefinedFunction");
```

So no matter what the result is. The user defined function will be called automatically to compare the array values. If you don't want to call your 'compareOptions' function, then you can go for **array_diff_assoc($array1,$array2)**. This will use built in function to compare both keys and values of the arrays.

Comment: Yeah. I do need to use my custom comparing function. That's why I use array_udiff_assoc().
What I don't understand is why after getting the result of it and 'compareVariants' function returning 0, script steps into 'compareOptions' again comparing the up-level arrays. What am I missing?

Comment: Because you have called the compareOptions function inside compareVariants. Your compareVariants function returns value only after the function array_udiff_assoc executed. So, first compareVariants function will be called and when the function array_udiff_assoc executed, it will automatically call its custom function (in your case it is compareOptions).

Comment: Probably, I'm not completely clear. 'compareOptions' is called second time when 'compareVariants' function returns 0. Moreover 'compareOptions' starts to compare higher level arrays which it's not supposed to. That's my problem. I wonder why it does that.